# Temporarily disable one or several voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there any way to temporarily disable one or several voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking? I don't want to have to remove and add them later on, or rename them one by one.

Comment: The only way I know is to remove them

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, same here, not very convenient :/

Comment: Just put the n-word in front of each command ;)

Comment: @Mark It's a bit painful to rename them one by one.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt What I am doing is, most times, having the command call out to an AutoIt3 script file since that ends up being the best way to do what I want done, and stops me from having to use their awful dialog. I would recommend installing AutoIt3 (windows only) if you can, If you do that I could write you a script to do whatever with your commands.